# MSsql trigger for DELETE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want the trigger to prevent deletion of an employee from the Role-table if that employee is already working on a task. If the task hasn't started, the employee should be able to be deleted from the Role-table.

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_role_del
ON Role
FOR DELETE AS

IF EXISTS (SELECT Task.StartTask, Role.EmployeeId,
FROM Task, Role, deleted
WHERE Role.EmployeeId = deleted.EmployeeId
AND Role.EmployeeId = Task.EmployeeId
AND GETDATE() > Task.StartTask)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('This role is working on a task, cannot be removed', 16, 1)
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END;
```

Delete statement:

```
DELETE FROM Role
WHERE EmplyeeId = '003'
```

However the trigger above does not work. All deletes goes through, the trigger doesn't stop anything. If the SELECT-statement is run separately by itself it does select the right values from the tables, so the SELECT seems fine. I can't seem to get the code to work properly. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with an instead of delete trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_role_del
ON Role
INSTEAD OF DELETE AS

DELETE r
FROM Role r
INNER JOIN deleted ON r.EmployeeId = deleted.EmployeeId
LEFT JOIN Task ON r.EmployeeId = Task.EmployeeId
               AND GETDATE() > Task.StartTask
WHERE Task.Id IS NULL -- Any non-nullable column on the task table is good here
```

[See a live demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/YDWZ75350)

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful, it solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You created an "AFTER DELETE" Trigger, while you should create a "INSTEAD OF" trigger.

Comment: This is a great comment but a very poor answer.